What book has an alien species of explorers finding a radioactive earth with a signal coming from a human moonbase?
I read this book a while ago but I can't remember the name or author. It's been about 20 years since I read it and I'd like to reread it. It took place in our immediate future and a long time from now, jumping back and forth.
Humanity destroyed the Earth in nuclear war and the moon-base, after a number of problems, had to develop cryo-pods. There was a part where a shuttle missed the rendezvous with the moon and couldn't return to it, so they used it to hit Venus at the right speed and angle to speed up its rotation. The survivors of the moon-base develop cryo-pods to wait out the long time for Venus to be suitable to inhabit.
In the far future, an alien species exploring the galaxy comes across a signal. They track it back to a star system only to find it originates from the moon of a radioactive planet (Earth) and not the lush planet (Venus) and investigate. They discover a human moon-base and investigate only to learn about humans. End of the book they find the cryo-pods and wake the humans up.

Oh no I've read this and I can't remember the title.  This is going to bother me all day. XD

Yeah, it's been bugging me for a couple years now. Google is NO help...
